# Android Using different string for ProductFlavor

Tags: android, gradle

I have an app with several productFlavors and I have a case where there is a string in the /main/res/values/strings.xml (R.string.foo_title) that for one product flavor I wanted to be a different string.

I added a R.string.foo_title under the product flavors res/values/strings.xml and expected the resource merge to replace the string for that flavor with the one I changed but it didn't.

I guess I expected this to just work but had a hard time finding examples of how the resource merge worked in this case. Am I wrong to expect that behavior?

I can see a couple of options to fix this but they seem less than optimal:

- Remove the id from /main/res/values and make all flavors have their own R.string.foo_title. (Then I have no default value)
- Change the id to a product flavor specific id. (If I happen to accidentally re-use a string id I'll have the same issue)

Any ideas?

Comment: Post your code & what is your current output and expected result?

Comment: Have you changed the build variant prior making the build?

Comment: @YuvaRaj not really any code to post. It's an Activity in the productFlavor folder calling getString(R.string.foo_title) and it returns the string defined in the main/res/values/strings.xml vs the foo/res/values/string.xml

Comment: @AndyRes yes I've changed the build variant to fooDebug

Comment: From my experience, I've seen the same thing you did. The merger won't replace existing keys, so you'd need to do option 1: pull that string out into separate resource files for each flavor. However, that does seem like unexpected behavior, so I'd love to know if there's another way.

Answer (score 0):

This does work as I expected. At some point I needed to do a full clean and rebuild and it just started working.

If you are experiencing odd behavior try a clean rebuild.